# Which Transformation, Or Similarity Metric, Is Rotation, Shift and Scale Invariant?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, algorithms, transform

I have an algorithm to to detect copy-move forgeries in images. I used block matching to detect regions of an image that were forged with copy-move forgery and highlighted the alleged areas. For block matching, I took the DCT of each block and normalized with an extended 16x16 quantization matrix.

The problem:

- this approach does not work if the copied region is rotated or scaled.

My question:

- What transformation/similarity metric would be invariant to rotations, shifts, and scaling? (Alternatively, is there another method available for solving this problem?)
- Additional points if the method is already available in MATLAB.

Thanks for the help.

The code for this project is available here: [copy-move forgery detection](https://github.com/BradySheehan/copy_move_forgery_detection).

Edit: I am aware of the Radial Gradient Transform, but I don't think it is invariant to all three.

Comment: there's wavelet families whose bases in essence contain mother wavelets and scaled versions; that would possibly solve the scale-invariance issue. However, this sounds like you'd have to come up with your "own" wavelet.

Comment: I'll have to consider wavelets more closely. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Your question has a close 1D version here http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/25926/quantitative-comparison-of-scaled-delayed-and-warped-signals

Answer (score 1):

Use a methods called Error Level Analysis (ELA). It can solve your problem as many forensic applications use it to detected doctored reigns in digital images.

Answer (score 1):

There are several feature descriptors for an image that are scale, rotation and shift-invariant. Two examples are [SIFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform#Overview) and [SURF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speeded_up_robust_features).

You can extract feature points from one images and see, if you find the same feature descriptors in another image. This will very likely identify a match between both images.

Comment: Coming back a little late, can you detail why you term them "scale, rotation and shift-invariant"?